# Responsive website redirected in iframe isn't responsive

Tags: html, css, redirect, iframe, responsive-design

I have multiple domains who redirect to the same responsive website by iFrame.

The problem is, when I visit these website's on a mobile device, it's not longer responsive.

The original website, http://m.isero.nl/, works perfect.
But it's not longer responsive when I use a domain who redirect by frame, like http://iseroijzerwarengroep.be/.

How can I make this website responsive to mobile devices inside an iFrame?

I tried this in my css:

```
iframe, object, embed{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

But no success.

Comment: iframes are old and bad.. especially in your case.. please do not "redirect" with iframe.. you should use .htaccess or other server settings to do this.

Comment: @Hardy You're confusing frames and iframes. Granted, iframes certainly have their issues but sometimes they are the only choice. Frames are pretty much never a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your parent sites don't have the appropriate `viewport` meta-tag in the `<head>`. That tag is present in the child site:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: True, but I don't have access to the parent sites head part, can't I solve this in the child site?

Comment: An iframe cannot modify it's parent (unless the parent is coded to permit it)

Comment: then what's the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a .php document and upload it to your hosting. Don't create a frame forward in your domain setting, but point the domain to the created .php document. Then use the following code in your .php document to create the frame forward there.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum- 
scale=1.0; user-scalable=0">
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
</head>
<frameset rows="100%" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
<frame name="main" src="https://your-target-domain.com/" marginwidth="0" 
marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" 
noresize="noresize">
</frameset>
<noframes>
</noframes>
</html>
```

I created a link to a favicon as well. You can take this line out if you dont need it. If you need it, simply upload your favicon as "favicon.ico" into the same directory as the .php file.

Now you have a mobile responsive frame forwarding :)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP method recommended by Timm worked like a magic. Check https://shop.wavessystems.com/ redirecting to https://shop.wati.io/075a04d0-5098-4d8f-ad9d-d34e048666c5 without affecting the responsiveness on mobile view.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32619414)